# Removing runner settings from Task Runner Explorer webpack.config.js in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, visual-studio-2019, task-runner-explorer, webpack-config

In my Task Runner Explorer, There are too many runner settings(Run, Profile, Serve, Watch).
For each of the categories, there are 4 items, the one I actually use is the one before the last one of the Watch category. Is there a way to remove the rest from the display?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue in VS2022...did you find out how to remove these old configurations?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem on VS2022.
GitHub issue is also opened: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebPackTaskRunner/issues/60

Comment: Nothing new on my end